# Jupyter Notebook: Multiple notebook to one kernel?

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm doing some complicated works with Jupyter Notebook, so the notebook is very long (https://github.com/cqcn1991/Wind-Speed-Analysis).

Sometimes, during the middle of the notebook, I want to do some additional analysis. Adding them directly into the current notebook (in the middle) may make it more complex, and breaks its currecnt structure. I think it would be amazing if I can simply open another notebook, connect it to the existing notebook's kernel, then to do the additional analysis.

Something may like

```
# In the new notebook
connect_to 'exisiting_notebook_name' # get access to the existing notebook
df.describe()
# ...
# some additional analysis works
```

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The [scratchpad](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/scratchpad) notebook extension sounds like exactly what you want.

Comment: what if I want a truly independent notebook instead that just a small thing as scratchpad seems to do?